# How to change bower-installer path for one component

Tags: javascript, node.js, bower, bower-install

I am using bower-installer to copy files I need from bower_components folder into bower_dist folder. Here is relevant part of bower.json file:

```
"install": {
    "path": "bower_dist"
},
"dependencies": {
    "jquery": "~2.1.4",
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.4",
    "slick.js": "~1.5.5"
},
```

Now this is creating bower_dist folder and within it folder for each component. The problem is that within slick.js component I have few files (eot, svg, ttf, woff) that I need to have in `/slick.js/fonts` folder (rather than just `/slick.js/` folder).

How do I do this? I've tried specifying special case for eot, svg, ttf and woff, but then that gets applied to all components. Plus I don't want to introduce need to specify all file types (js, css, etc)... rather want to just configure special font type for slick.js. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This proved to be tougher than I thought:

```
"install": {
    "path": "bower_dist",
    "sources": {
        "slick-carousel": {
            "mapping": [
                { "bower_components/slick-carousel/slick/slick.min.js": "slick.min.js" },
                { "bower_components/slick-carousel/slick/slick.css": "slick.css" },
                { "bower_components/slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css": "slick-theme.css" },
                { "bower_components/slick-carousel/slick/ajax-loader.gif": "ajax-loader.gif" },
                { "bower_components/slick-carousel/slick/fonts/slick.eot": "fonts/slick.eot" },
                { "bower_components/slick-carousel/slick/fonts/slick.svg": "fonts/slick.svg" },
                { "bower_components/slick-carousel/slick/fonts/slick.ttf": "fonts/slick.ttf" },
                { "bower_components/slick-carousel/slick/fonts/slick.woff": "fonts/slick.woff" }
            ]
        }
    }
},
```

I've upgraded to new version of slick.js and now it's called slick-carousel in bower - just to explain difference in package name.

Answer (score 6):

The problem here appears to be that *slick.js* uses a glob pattern in their [`bower.json`](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/blob/master/bower.json) `main` file array which is [not supported...](http://bower.io/docs/creating-packages/#main)

> Globs like `js/*.js` are **not allowed**.

You should do the following...

1. Override the required files for *slick.js* in your `bower.json` file (see [*Install multiple main files*](https://github.com/blittle/bower-installer#install-multiple-main-files) and [*Configurable paths*](https://github.com/blittle/bower-installer#configurable-paths))

   ```
   "install": {
       "base": "bower_dist",
       "path": {
           "js": "{name}",
           "css": "{name}",
           "eot": "{name}/fonts",
           "svg": "{name}/fonts",
           "ttf": "{name}/fonts",
           "woff": "{name}/fonts"
       },
       "sources": {
           "slick.js": [
               "bower_components/slick.js/slick/slick.min.js",
               "bower_components/slick.js/slick/slick.css",
               "bower_components/slick.js/slick/slick-theme.css",
               "bower_components/slick.js/slick/fonts/slick.eot",
               "bower_components/slick.js/slick/fonts/slick.svg",
               "bower_components/slick.js/slick/fonts/slick.ttf",
               "bower_components/slick.js/slick/fonts/slick.woff"
           ]
       }
   }
   ```

   Substitute `bower_components` for whatever your bower install directory is.
2. Follow [this pull request](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/pull/1529).

Comment: As soon as I add "sources": { "slick.js": ... command bower-installer stops publishing slick.js. Are you sure that's proper format? I've also tried modifying bower.json from slick.js the way you did it in pull request but still it doesn't work - it doesn't create proper folder structure.

Comment: @kape123 I was just following the bower-installer documentation ~ https://github.com/blittle/bower-installer#install-multiple-main-files. Looks like you need to prefix the file path with your bower install directory. I'll update my answer with an example

Comment: yeah when I put it like that, it copies files. But it again puts them all in the same directory - /bower_dist/slick.js/ ... it doesn't create fonts directory for fonts. ;(

Comment: @kape123 then I'd guess you need to use the [configurable paths](https://github.com/blittle/bower-installer#configurable-paths)

Comment: Those would mess up all components, which is not something I wanted as I explained in the question. I am granting you bounty since you helped, but I am adding correct answer on my own. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @kape123 glad you got it sorted. I wasn't sure if the file-type path mapping would work for you but it was worth a shot. Last resort would have been the individual file mapping which it seems is what you needed.